# How to "sum" product weight if the product are in different lines?

Tags: mysql, sum

I have to sum the weight of the certain products, but they are in different lines of MySQL. How to do it?

Here is an example of my database:

```
ID | Product_id | weight_kg | Quantity | 
1  | 201        | 6         | 3        | 
2  | 102        | 3         | 1        | 
3  | 103        | 4         | 4        | 
4  | 200        | 2         | 1        | 
5  | 201        | 6.3       | 7        | 
6  | 205        | 1         | 7        |
```

For example I would like to know, how much is the weight of all the products starting with the `product_id` `"2"(200,201,205)`.

Comment: Do you want to factor in quantities?  I am assuming you do.

Comment: Pls provide an example of expected output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer for SQL Server would be:

```
SELECT SUM(weight_kg * Quantity) AS Weight
FROM table
WHERE Product_id LIKE '2%'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUM(weight_kg * Quantity) FROM table_name WHERE Product_id LIKE '2%'
```

Comment: But that doesn't factor in quantities.

Comment: OK, now it does, you didn't ask for that in your question but in any case I should have speculated that you might have wanted that :)